# How can I hide persistent Facetime audio call on macOS?

Tags: macos, facetime

When I'm on a Facetime audio call, I'm not able to hide or minimize or move that persistent audio call banner. It covers important UI of may apps so I can't click on anything underneath it.

[image: fact]

Comment: I don't use it often enough to be able to test, but what do you have set in Notifications Prefs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqky9.png

Comment: Just like your example. Banners. And other settings the same too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Enable Do Not Disturb and the banner will disappear even when on the call.

You can enable Do Not Disturb from the Notification Center. You can access the Notification Center by clicking the Notification Center icon at the top right of the screen. Or by sliding two fingers on the trackpad, from right to left but starting from the outside of the trackpad.

Comment: alt/option click on Notification Center icon is the fastest way to toggle DND, does that work in this situation too?

Comment: @grg had no idea. Nice tip. Yes, it works.